# Web Service to connect Android Phone with ASP.net MVC 4 Application

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, web-services, web, synchronization

I recently have created my application in asp.net mvc4, now I want to create a web service that will be used to sync data between web application and android phone. What would be preferable to start with ?

Answer (score 1):

[Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net) is a great library that will help you communicate from your client to a server using REST.